# Training data on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am relatively new to AWS and I'm trying to analyze credit fraud data set available on kaggle. I'm using doing it by looking at the example mentioned in the link "https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/preprocess-input-data-before-making-predictions-using-amazon-sagemaker-inference-pipelines-and-scikit-learn/". I uploaded my credit card data set into my s3 bucket and done the following

```
import boto3 
import botocore 
import pandas as pd
import sagemaker
from sagemaker import get_execution_role 
role = get_execution_role() 
bucket = '<mybucket>' 
prefix = 'test'
key = 'creditcard.csv' 
data_location = 's3://{}/{}/train/{}'.format(bucket,prefix,key)  
output_location = 's3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix)
containers = {
          <mycontainer>
          }
sess = sagemaker.Session()
linear = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(containers[boto3.Session().region_name],
                                   role, 
                                   train_instance_count=1, 
                                   train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
                                   output_path=output_location,
                                   sagemaker_session=sess)
linear.set_hyperparameters(feature_dim=31,
                       predictor_type='binary_classifier',
                       mini_batch_size=50)
linear.fit({'train': data_location})
```

When I try to run this code, an error message is popping up showing "Either the training channel is empty or the mini-batch size is too high. Verify that training data contains non-empty files and the mini-batch size is less than the number of records per training host"
My training data doesn't have any empty files. How to deal with this error ?
*I uploaded the data set from my PC and stored in my bucket inside the folder named test
*The container is standard one used for linear learner
* I think I somehow couldn't connect the file from s3 bucket to the notebook instance I created. Can anyone verify that

Comment: which container are you using? built-in linear regression?

Answer (score 0):

Please double check your the value of the `data_location` var that was passed into the `fit()` call and make sure it is what you expect it to be. You should also check it with the aws cli (i.e. `aws s3 ls $data_location`).

If it all looks ok to you then you'll need to help us to investigate further. Unfortunately that's only possible if we have the details of the training job that failed. You can initiate that conversation over at the SageMaker forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=285